# How to cut the output of a powershell command?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a powershell script which writes data into a MS SQL database.
I use the command **get-winevent**.

The row `Message` is very long and includes not required data e.q. SID etc.

How can I cut the output of this command?

**Update**

The code snippet looks like:

```
$events = Get-WinEvent @{LogName = "System"; ID = 4726} | select LevelDisplayName, LogName, TaskDisplayName, TimeCreated,@{N='Message';E={
$m = [regex]::Match($_.Message, '.*Account Name: (?<account>[^ ]*).*Account Domain: (?<domain>[^ ]*).*')
"Account Name: $($m.Groups['account']) Account Domain: $($m.Groups['domain'])"
}}

$events
```

The output in the console looks like:

> LevelDisplayName : Information 
>   LogName          : Security 
>   TaskDisplayName  : User Account Management 
>   TimeCreated      : 18.07.2016 11:55:42 
>   Message          : Account Name:   username_xxx  Account Domain:

How you can see between the `Account Name:` and the value are some empty impacts. How can I ignore this empty impacts?

Comment: What does cut mean to you? You need to truncate message, ignore message?

Comment: Yes, I want to truncate the row message. Now the output is:

 A user account was deleted. Subject: Security ID: SID_xxx Account Name: username_xxx Account Domain: domain_xxxx Logon ID:  Target Account: Security ID: SID_xxx Account Name: name_xxx Account Domain: domain_xxx Additional Information: Privileges -

I would only like to display the Account name and the account domain.

Comment: What is the result of `Get-WinEvent @{LogName = "System"; ID = 4726} | select -ExpandProperty Message -First 5`?

Comment: It shows me this:
A user account was deleted.

Subject:
        Security ID:            MySecurityID
        Account Name:           myusername
        Account Domain:         mydomain
        Logon ID:               0x30ffebc

Target Account:
        Security ID:            my securityid
        Account Name:           myusername
        Account Domain:         mydomain

Additional Information:
        Privileges      -

Comment: Updated test case, still works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Get-WinEvent | select TimeCreated,@{N='Message';E={
  $split = $_.Message.Split('. ');
  if ($split.Length -gt 4){
    [string]::Join('. ', ($split[0], $split[4]))
  } else {
    $_.Message
  }
}}
```

According to your update:

```
Get-WinEvent | select TimeCreated,@{N='Message';E={
  $m = [regex]::Match($_.Message, '.*Account Name: (?<account>[^ ]*).*Account Domain: (?<domain>[^ ]*).*')
  "Account Name: $($m.Groups['account']) Account Domain: $($m.Groups['domain'])"
}}
```

Test case:

```
$arg = [PSCustomObject]@{TimeCreated=Get-Date;Message="A user account was deleted. Subject: Security ID: SID_xxx Account Name: username_xxx Account Domain: domain_xxxx Logon ID: Target Account: Security ID: SID_xxx Account Name: name_xxx Account Domain: domain_xxx Additional Information: Privileges"},
[PSCustomObject]@{TimeCreated=Get-Date;Message="A user account was deleted. Subject: Security ID: MySecurityID Account Name: myusername Account Domain: mydomain Logon ID: 0x30ffebc Target Account: Security ID: my securityid Account Name: myusername Account Domain: mydomain Additional Information: Privileges"},
[PSCustomObject]@{TimeCreated=Get-Date;Message="Account Domain: myuserdomain"},
[PSCustomObject]@{TimeCreated=Get-Date;Message="Account Name: myusername"}

$arg | select TimeCreated,@{N='Message';E={
  $n = [regex]::Match($_.Message, '.*Account Name: ([^ $]*).*')
  $d = [regex]::Match($_.Message, '.*Account Domain: ([^ $]*).*')
  $result = if ($n.Success) { "Account Name: $($n.Groups[1])" }

  if ($d.Success){
    if ($result) { $result += " Account Domain: $($d.Groups[1])" }
    else { $result = "Account Domain: $($d.Groups[1])" }
  }
  $result
}}
```

Returns:

```
TimeCreated           Message                                          
-----------           -------                                          
2016-08-30 08:03:57   Account Name: name_xxx Account Domain: domain_xxx
2016-08-30 08:03:57   Account Name: myusername Account Domain: mydomain
2016-08-30 08:03:57   Account Domain: myuserdomain                     
2016-08-30 08:03:57   Account Name: myusername
```

Comment: I think OP want only some parts of `Message` and not exclude it.

Comment: Which parts do you need? Can you edit your question and specify?

Comment: Thank you very much for the update! The represention is very good but there are no values for the account name and the account domain - just an empty impact.

Comment: Are you sure your string is in mentioned format? Are you sure all Messages has this format?

Comment: @PawełDyl Sorry for my late answer. I saw that the string is in another format. The format is so:
Account Domain:        myusername
How can we edit the script that it skips the empty impact and gets the username?

Comment: Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: Replaced regexes, added another test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You might use Substring.

```
Get-WinEvent ... |
    Select-Object TimeCreated, @{n='Message';e={
        if ($_.Message.Length -gt 500) {
            $_.Message.Substring(0, 500)
        } else {
            $_.Message
        }
    }}
```

Attempting to pick out sentences. This re-assembles the first and fifth sentence from the message. If the fifth is blank you'll only get the first. Trim is used to clean off unnecessary new lines.

```
Get-WinEvent ... |
    Select-Object TimeCreated, @{n='Message';e={ 
        $message = $_.Message -split '\. '
        ($message[0] + "`r`n" + $message[4]).Trim()
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works, I can cut some parts of the output. Do you now if I can cut multiple parts of one command? e.g. I'd like to have the first sentence and the fifth sentence.

Comment: If we say that a sentence is delimited by a period followed by a space we might get away with it. It's a bit rough to say the least. I'll update the example.